# ssh-add in a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, ssh-agent

I've mounted the `~/.ssh` directory into my development docker container from the host machine and trying to add the deployment key to the ssh agent in the entrypoint like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

#add the deployment key
if [[ ! -z ${DEPLOYMENT_SSH_KEY} ]] ; then
    echo "Adding deployment ssh key ${DEPLOYMENT_SSH_KEY} to ssh agent"
    eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /.ssh/${DEPLOYMENT_SSH_KEY}
else
    echo "Deployment ssh key is not defined"
fi

echo "STARTING PHP FPM, CMD $@"

docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

The key gets normally added according to the logs:

> Agent pid 8
>
> Adding deployment ssh key id_rsa to ssh agent
>
> Identity added: /.ssh/id_rsa (rsa w/o comment)

However, it actually ends up with no keys added to the agent and I can't clone my repos from inside the container. The command `ssh-add -l` executed in the container says

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Why's that? I heard of the SSH agent forwarding as an alternative but I'm wondering why the method I've tried doesn't work?

Comment: Does `docker-php-entrypoint` end up switching the running process to be a different user?

Comment: @DanLowe it uses `exec` to run the command: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-entrypoint

Answer (score 0):

Since `ssh-add` error message says "could not connect" it either can't find `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable or can't access socket path contained in that variable.
Since `ssh-agent` use `/tmp` for the socket by default, guess your `/tmp` mountpoint is broken in some way.

Comment: The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` var is set, it can connect and add the key to the agent before launching php-fpm, i.e. before executing `docker-php-entrypoint "$@"` in the entrypoint